# How to write the sql statement for the below query?

Tags: sql, wampserver

i have a table(`lab_schedule`) columns as below,

```
c_code    labclass      day
EEI4163   2019-04-09   Sunday
EEI4362   2019-03-05   Monday
EEI4362   2019-04-07   Tuesday
EEI4456   2019-05-06   Wednesday
```

I want view the course codes which do not have lab class on 2019-03-05

```
select c_Code,labclass 
from lab_schedule 
where labclass != "2019-03-05" group by c_code,labclass;
```

i tried to get the result by using the group by syntax in sql. but I expected only `EEI4163`, `EEI4456` but it shows `EEI4362` too which is in `2019-04-07`.

But EEI4362 course has a lab class on 2019-03-05.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self-outer join as an alternative solution like below:

```
select l1.c_Code, l1.labclass
from lab_schedule l1
left outer join lab_schedule l2 on l1.c_Code = l2.c_Code and l2.labclass = '2019-03-05'
where l2.c_Code is null
group by l1.c_Code, l1.labclass
```

Edit: If you wanna see only c_code, remove l1.labclass from "select" and "group by" statements.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select c_Code
from lab_schedule
group by c_code
having sum(case when labclass = '2019-03-05' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code removes the rows `where labclass = "2019-03-05"` but if a course code has lab class on "2019-03-07" and in another date it will still be in the results with the row with the other date.
Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select s.c_Code, s.labclass, s.day
from lab_schedule s
where not exists (
  select 1 from lab_schedule 
  where c_Code = s.c_Code and labclass = "2019-03-05"
)
```

If you want only the `c_Code` column

```
select distinct s.c_Code
from lab_schedule s
where not exists (
  select 1 from lab_schedule 
  where c_Code = s.c_Code and labclass = "2019-03-05"
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wBfCvdAhAzGm6rnhqy1dV8/1).
Results:

Comment: I want view the course codes which do not have lab class on 2019-03-05 is the question

Comment: If you want only the c_Code column then see my edited answer.